# Como utilizar elementos html dentro de tabela com Datatable

Tags: html, datatable

Como configuro o Datatables para compilar código html?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A Intenção era deixar o texto "Ativo" em verde ou na cor que indica sucesso de acordo com o tema.

Código de Inicialização da tabela:

```js
const altbl = $('#trimestre-table').DataTable({
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                ajax: '{!! route('datatables.trimestre') !!}',
                columns: [
                    {data: 'id', name: 'id'},
                    {data: 'descricao', name: 'descricao'},
                    {data: 'ini', name: 'ini'},
                    {data: 'fin', name: 'fin'},
                    {data: 'status', name: 'is_active'},
                    {
                        defaultContent: "<a href='#!' class='m-r-15 text-muted' id='edit' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' title='' data-original-title='Editar'><i class='icofont icofont-ui-edit'></i></a>"
                            + "<a href='#!' class='text-muted' id='delete' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' title='' data-original-title='Deletar'><i class='icofont icofont-delete-alt'></i></a>",
                        className: 'action-icon text-center'
                    }
                ],
                language: {
                    "sEmptyTable": "Nenhum registro encontrado",
                    "sInfo": "Mostrando de _START_ até _END_ de _TOTAL_ registros",
                    "sInfoEmpty": "Mostrando 0 até 0 de 0 registros",
                    "sInfoFiltered": "(Filtrados de _MAX_ registros)",
                    "sInfoPostFix": "",
                    "sInfoThousands": ".",
                    "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ resultados por página",
                    "sLoadingRecords": "Carregando...",
                    "sProcessing": "Processando...",
                    "sZeroRecords": "Nenhum registro encontrado",
                    "sSearch": "Pesquisar ",
                    "oPaginate": {
                        "sNext": "Próximo",
                        "sPrevious": "Anterior",
                        "sFirst": "Primeiro",
                        "sLast": "Último"
                    },
                    "oAria": {
                        "sSortAscending": ": Ordenar colunas de forma ascendente",
                        "sSortDescending": ": Ordenar colunas de forma descendente"
                    }
                },
                initComplete: function (settings, json) {
                    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
                },
                order: [[0, "desc"]],
            });
```

Comment: Coloque `console.log(json);` na function do `initComplete` e veja o que mostra.

Comment: Devo procurar algo em especifico? Não entendi...

Comment: Vai retornar um JSON, correto? Veja o que mostra nesse JSON o valor onde tem esse `span`?

Comment: Mostra os dados mas com html entities

Comment: No banco de dados tb está com html entities?